# Find the derivative of $f(t)=(25-t)\times e^{0.1t}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been trying to find the derivative of the function for quite a while but I just can't find it.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: try https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: It's really tough to understand what you mean.

Comment: That edit is incorrect, look at my question, i believe thats the function the user wants

Answer (score 3):

$f(t) = (25-t)e^{0.1t}$.

First understand that there are two functions: $(25 - t)$, and $(e^{0.1t})$. Thus we have to apply product rule, but notice that to differentiate $(e^{0.1t})$, we have a function in a function, so we must use chain rule here.

The derivative of $(25 - t)$ = $-1$.

The derivative of $(e^{0.1t}$) = $0.1e^{0.1t}.$

Doing the product rule, we have:

$$(h(x)g(x))' = h'(x)g(x) + h(x)g'(x)$$
$$((25-t)e^{0.1t})' = (-1)(e^{0.1t}) + (25 - t)(0.1e^{0.1t})$$

Comment: the derivative of $$25-t$$ with respect to $t$ is $-1$

Comment: My mistake, thanks

Comment: yes and i got the downvotes

Comment: Well u didnt explain it, u just "put" an answer. thats even worse

Comment: i have this explained now

Comment: That's better, answers should be explained (You have 23.3k Im sure you know this)

Comment: yes i know this